# C# - How to make a X509Certificate2UI window always on top

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

Is it possible to make X509Certificate2UI window always on top, or any other way to select certificate with window on top? I'm using `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection` method

Comment: How do you display the window? If it is okay that the window is on top of the parent window, you might use the overload that takes a handle to the parent window (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223191(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I use X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection method

Comment: That method also comes with an overload that takes a handle to the parent window. Are you using that overload?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the window stay on top of the parent window, if you pass a handle to the parent window to the function displaying the window, i.e. you need to use the following overload of the [`SelectFromCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223190(v=vs.110).aspx) method where `hwndParent` is set to the handle of the opening window:

```
public static X509Certificate2Collection SelectFromCollection(
    X509Certificate2Collection certificates,
    string title,
    string message,
    X509SelectionFlag selectionFlag,
    IntPtr hwndParent
)
```

In Windows Forms you can simply get the handle from the `Handle` property of the form:

```
IntPtr windowHandle = form.Handle;
```

If you are using WPF, you need to use the `WindowInteropHelper` class to retrieve the handle:

```
IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
```

Comment: Is there any way to position the Select Certificate dialog on Center of Parent form ?

Comment: You can also use `windowHandle = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle`.